# Structure SQLite3 query in PHP

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm quite new to PHP and SQLite.

Is it possible to structure a SQLite3 query in PHP into a table?

I have the following code:

```
$result = $db->query('SELECT unique_id, description FROM dis_enums WHERE unique_id <= 12');
while ($row = $result->fetchArray()){
    print_r($row);
    echo nl2br("\n");
}
```

Which returns the following:

```
Array( [0] => 1 [unique_id] => 1 [1] => Concrete [description] => Concrete )

Array( [0] => 2 [unique_id] => 2 [1] => Bridge [description] => Bridge )
```

etc.

Is there any way to change my code so it has headers (unique_id and description) with the results underneath?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `DISTINCT` as `SELECT DISTINCT unique_id, description...`

Comment: @Saty Thanks for your reply. I thought DISTINCT was used to eliminate all duplicate records and fetch only unique records? This is not what I am trying to do. Apologies if my question isn't clear. I'm trying to arrange the results from my query into a more readable manner (a table with headers.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can echo the headers before the content of your table.
If you want to construct a html-table that would look like that:

```
$result = $db->query('SELECT unique_id, description FROM dis_enums WHERE unique_id <= 12');
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>unique_id</th><th>description</th>";
echo "</tr>";
while ($row = $result->fetchArray()){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['unique_id'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['description'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo "</table>";
```

There is a almost matching example here http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitephp/